# Google Places API Web Service vs Google Places API for Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

Which one is recommended for `AutoCompleteText` for places.

`Google Places API Web Service` or `Google Places API for Android`.

Which gives the optimal results?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to use with autocomplete?  What exact type of functionality are you trying to implement?

Comment: autocomplete Google places

Answer (score 0):

You can use either, they both provide autocomplete results, though you would need to connect the results to an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

If you would like to use a library that provides a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget ([demo](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android/blob/master/samples/images/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.gif)), check out [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (I'm the developer).  After setting it up with your API key, you could add a working Places API autocomplete to your layout with something like:

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```